# Using values of a list stored in DataFrame cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a CSV file with each cell value a two element list(pair).

```
    |   0       |   1        |    2    | 
----------------------------------------
0   |[87, 1.03] | [30, 4.05] |   NaN   |
1   |[34, 2.01] |   NaN      |   NaN   |
2   |[83, 0.2]  | [18, 3.4]  |   NaN   |
```

How do I access the elements of these, separately? The first element of each pair acts as an index for another CSV table.
I have done something like this, but this keeps bugging me on one thing or other.

```
links = pd.read_csv('buslinks.csv', header = None)
a_list = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    l = []
    a_list.append(l)
for j in range(0, 100):
    a = busStops.iloc[j]
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'Distance'])
    l = links.iloc[j]
    for i in l:
        if(pd.isnull(i)):
            continue
        else:
            x = int(i[0])
            d = busStops.iloc[x-1]
            id = d['id']
            dist = distance(d['xCoordinate'], a['xCoordinate'], d['yCoordinate'], a['yCoordinate'])
            df.loc[i] = [id, dist]
    a_list[j] = (df.sort('Distance', ascending = True)).tolist()
```

This approach worked when each cell contained only one element. In that case, np.isnan() was used instead of pd.isnull()

The read CSV file was created as:

```
a_list = []
for i in range(0, 100):
    l = []
    a_list.append(l)
for i in range(0, 100):
    while(len(a_list[i])<3):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        if(x-1 == i):
             continue
        a = busStops.iloc[i]
        b = busStops.iloc[x-1]
        dist = distance(a['xCoordinate'], b['xCoordinate'], a['yCoordinate'], b['yCoordinate'])
        if dist>3:
            continue
        if x in a_list[i]:
            continue
        a_list[i].append([b['id'], dist])
        a_list[x-1].append([a['id'], dist])
    for j in range(0, 3):
        y = random.randint(0, 1)
        while (y == 0):
            x = random.randint(1, 100)
            if(x-1 == i):
                 continue
            a = busStops.iloc[i]
            b = busStops.iloc[x-1]
            dist = distance(a['xCoordinate'], b['xCoordinate'], a['yCoordinate'], b['yCoordinate'])
            if dist>3:
                continue
            if x in a_list[i]:
                continue
            a_list[i].append([b['id'], dist])
            a_list[x-1].append([a['id'], dist])
            y = 1
dfLinks = pd.DataFrame(a_list)
dfLinks
dfLinks.to_csv('buslinks.csv', index = False, header = False)
```

BusStops is yet another CSV file, that contains id, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, Population and Priority as columns.

Comment: @jpp I have edited the question to include how I managed to get the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, beware that storing lists in DataFrames dooms you to Python-speed loops. To take advantage of fast Pandas/NumPy routines, you need to use native NumPy dtypes such as np.float64 (whereas, in contrast, list require "object" dtype).

That being said, here is my code i wrote just to show how to do it so you can use something like that in your code:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
table.loc[0] = [1, 2,3]
table.loc[1] = [1, [2,3], 4]

table.loc[1].iloc[1]        # returns [2, 3]
table.loc[1].iloc[1][0]     # returns 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that yes, using it the way I desired, made it a lot inefficient. Just for help, should I make another CSV file, to put the distance value (second element of pair), or should I rely on recalculating it every time?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to achieve. If you have a lot of calculations, then put it in the CSV, but consider putting the elements from list in DataFrames to separate columns. If you don't expect to have a lot of data, just recalculate it every time. Also, depends how often you'll be recalculating it. But that's up to you, just bare in mind that performing I/O operations also takes time. The best way is to test it with `time.time()`

Comment: Okay, Thanks again! :)

Comment: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (3,) + inhomogeneous part.` when running your code with pandas                    2.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be putting lists in `pd.Series` objects. It's inefficient and you lose all vectorised functionality. If, however, you are determined that this *must* be your starting point, you can unravel the lists into multiple columns in a couple of steps.

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [[87, 1.03], [34, 2.01], [83, 0.2]],
                   1: [[30, 4.05], np.nan, [18, 3.4]],
                   2: [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
```

**Step 1: ensure lists have same size**

```
# messy way to ensure all values have length 2
df[1] = np.where(df[1].isnull(), pd.Series([[np.nan, np.nan]]*len(df[1])), df[1])

print(df)

            0           1   2
0  [87, 1.03]  [30, 4.05] NaN
1  [34, 2.01]  [nan, nan] NaN
2   [83, 0.2]   [18, 3.4] NaN
```

**Step 2: concatenate dataframes of split series**

```
# create list of dataframes
L = [pd.DataFrame(df[col].values.tolist()) for col in df]

# concatenate dataframes in list
df_new = pd.concat(L, axis=1, ignore_index=True)

print(df_new)

    0     1     2     3   4
0  87  1.03  30.0  4.05 NaN
1  34  2.01   NaN   NaN NaN
2  83  0.20  18.0  3.40 NaN
```

You can then access values as you would normally, e.g. `df_new[2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think my way of putting lists in DataFrame is indeed making my work way more difficult and inefficient.